# Opening A Batch File In Notepad++ In The Folder Where Notepad++ Is Opened

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

I Made A Batch File Which Would Open In Notepad++ From The CURRENT DIRECTORY where the batch file is located(with run.. feature in notepad++), But I Want batch file to open on the folder where i have opened the file.
Example:
My Batch File Is Located In `D:\Projects\Java\Executor Java.bat`
I Have Opened A File Of .java Extension in `D:\Java\Files`
I Want to open at file location,i.e. `D:\Java\Files`
My batch file Looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO                                        WELCOME TO EXECUTOR
ECHO                                                         -Garvit Joshi(garvitjoshi9@gmail.com)
ECHO                                                          USER:%USERNAME%
cd /d "%~dp0"
:first
ECHO LOOKING FOR FILES IN:"%~dp0"
set /p "input=Enter The File You Want To Execute:"
ECHO ===============================
javac %input%.java
ECHO ===============================
set /p "input=Enter The Class You Want To Run:"
ECHO ===============================
ECHO OUTPUT:
ECHO ===============================
java %input%
ECHO ===============================
pause
ECHO =======================================================
ECHO *******************************************************
ECHO =======================================================
goto first
```

Comment: Do you realize, that `cd /d "%~dp0"` changes the working folder to the folder where the batch file resides?

Comment: Yes !! i Am Not Getting the appropriate snippet to add on that line so that batch file opens up in current working directory.

Comment: The current working folder is `%cd%`. But no need to *change* to that, because that *is already*  the working folder.

Comment: If I Use ```%cd% ``` the directory becomes ```c:\Program Files\Notepad++```

Comment: sorry, your description is a bit confusing. Do you want to change to `D:\Java\Files`?

Comment: yes, only if i have opened a file that is located ```D:\Java\Files```. If I Have opened a file in ```C:\Java\Files``` the batch file should be opened in that location in notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass the path as a parameter from Notepad++ in the 'Run...' dialog, e.g:

```
cmd /c "D:\Projects\Java\ExecutorJava.bat $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
```

..then have your batch file use the parameter with something like:

```
cd /d "%1"
```

(In this example, have removed the space from the "Executor Java.bat" filename for convenience)